# How to have multiple options when I tried to create a class using flutter?

Tags: json, dart

This is what I mean:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYLta.png)

and in my Visual Studio Code, I only have the option “add 'late' modifier”

How can I have all the options from the screen in my Visual Studio Code?

Thanks

Comment: can you clarify

Comment: Of course, do you see the image that I post? If not click on  "enter image description here", in that image shows a bunch of options and I don't know how to get that options, I discovered that image because I'm making a tutorial on YouTube and in my VS Code I don't have that wide comprehensive options, if you can help me I really appreciate.

Comment: Find out the kind of IDE (and possibly extensions, plugins, etc.) they are using in that video tutorial. That should solve your question.

Comment: Thank you @Ber, I do my research and the extension it's called "Dart Data Class Generator"

Comment: @caroc Thanks for the hint. However, that extension seems to be IntelliJ specific.

Comment: @Ber maybe is only for Visual Studio Code